# What's the best way to do this? Wordpress, pages, or plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to write a page which allows a user to select price packages, and then the package selected's details are sent to the user's email (which is specified in a textbox), how would I do this, with a page template, or a plugin?

I don't have much experience with Wordpress, so details would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a plug-in is a small program, or combination of programs, that sits on top of your WordPress installation and increases the functionality of your website in some way.

You say "*I need to write a page which allows a user to select price packages*". It sounds more like a contact form to me.

If you think you can write the script yourself, I would use a page dedicated to this purpose.

If not wordpress has some great contact form plugins, but they may not meet your exact demands. Here is an [example of such a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-contact-form/).

Comment: I don't understand how to get the form to send a specific email depending on what option was selected.

Comment: The form posts your users to a new page (you don't seem to want to use ajax). On that page you get the values `$_POST["your_options"]` and depending on them `if ($_POST["your_options"]=='option1') { //send this type of mail... }`

Comment: Thank you very, much, +1 and accept. And as for ajax, I do as much as the client wants, nothing more :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [cforms II](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) will do your requirement(s).

Comment: Why does it need to be Ajax driven?

Comment: why not? you doesn't say any specific requirement.